# iOS Start to send data to server from background when internet becomes available

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

Can we start to send data when internet is available while app is in background state by using `NSUrlsessionUploadTask` or anything else?

Comment: @Lion,did you get any solution for this?

Comment: This is not actually possible to get rechability change notification in background..!! I forgot to add answer i am writing now. @user2526811

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways(based on internet survey) that can achieve this kind of stuff(by `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` or background fetch) but not work smoothly, so we can say that it is not possible to get `rechability` change notification in background and start some task depends on it.

So, It is not possible to achieve this stuff exactly.

Comment: That's depends on your requirement that how you want to send your data to server and when!!!

Answer (score 2):

In order:

1. Create a background session configuration with the *discretionary* flag set.
2. Create a background session based on that configuration.
3. Create an upload task in that session.
4. Call its resume method.
5. Implement all the other bits for handling background session completion.